# navbar - How to change the 'link's color and font size' on a drop down menu when collasped only (not the link's color when it is full size)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

How to change the link's color and font size for the drop down menu when collapsed and NOT change the drop down menu when it is full size?
Here is visually what I'm asking: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2WYo.png)

Here is my present code: http://jsbin.com/bigoxeyuri/edit?css,output
You can see the links in the full size and the collapsed are two different colors - collapsed being the default gray that I want to change. 
Thank you.

```
    /*Navbar color full size and collapsed including drop down list*/
.navbar-default {
background-color: #B4A890;
border-color: #B4A890;
}

/*Link color for top links; but not drop down list*/
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
color: #f5ebdb; 
}

/*Link hover color; full size & collapsed; but not drop downlist*/
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
color: #110a02;
}


/* Drop down menu's Full Size only background color*/
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu 
{ background-color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 12px; /*size for full size and collapsed*/
}

/* Link color for drop down list & its rows' hover color for full size menu only*/
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus 
{
color: #f5ebdb;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #B4A890;
background-image: none;  
}


/* Drop down list Title Cell background collapsed & full*/
.dropdown-toggle:active, .open .dropdown-toggle 
{
        background:#f5ebdb !important; 
        color:#110a02 !important;
}

.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none; /* affects top main links*/
    background-color: white; /* ???Change rollover cell color here*/
  }

/*???BACKGROUND color for active*/
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active >   
 a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
color: #000000;
background-color: #ffffff;
}

/* 3-bar button - color */
.navbar-toggle {
    background-color: #B4A890;
}
/* 3-bar button - stripes */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #f5ebdb;
}

/* 3-bar button - color hover */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
background-color: #c2b89f;
}

/* 3-bar button - border */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #c2b89f;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the solution

```
/* solution */
    @media(max-width:768px){
      .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li {
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 16px;
      }
    }
```

i have updated your code 
[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wajepuhoci/1/edit?css,output)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you thank you kebir for your time and help :D

Answer (score 1):

The only time the navbar is collapsed is when the screen is a certain size in pixels. You should look into learning about media rules in CSS to learn more.

```
    @media (max-width: 767px) { //mobile width that collapses the navbar
        body {
            background-color: blue; //changes the background color to blue
        }
    }
```

[Here is an example on W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_media_example1)

Comment: Thank you for the advise. That explained the problem well Mitch Wilkins :D